# Only get the numbers from a variable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a simple script that shows me the currency value between BRL x USD, I got to the part where I get the value, but not as a float variable which I need for future conversion operations.

How do I get only the numbers in the `brlxusd` variable? Right now it prints out "0.253059 USD", I just want the "0.253059" part.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def currencyValues():
    url = urllib.urlopen('http://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=BRL&to=USD&amount=1')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")

    for usdbrl in soup.find_all("span", class_="ccOutputRslt"):
            brlxusd = usdbrl.text
            print "BRL x USD rate today: %s" % brlxusd

currencyValues()
```

Answer (score 2):

A fast and simple way is split the string in brlxusd and get the float part separated from USD part. your code inside for loop will be:

```
brlxusd = usdbrl.text
brlxusd = brlxusd.split(" ")[0]
# if you want to convert it to float use float(brlxusd.split(" ")[0])
print "BRL x USD rate today: %s" % brlxusd
```

This is assuming that all data will be in same format as you stated.

Comment: Didn't expect such a simple solution, works great! Ty

Comment: You don't need to pass a delimiter to split.

Comment: @DishantChavda, it is not good practice if you want to remove arbitrary whitespace which is what the OP is doing, passing a delimiter can in fact have an adverse effect.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get only the numbers in the brlxusd variable? Right now it
>   prints out "0.253059 USD", I just want the "0.253059" part.

```
>>> brlxusd = '0.253059 USD'
>>> brlxusd.split()[0]
'0.253059'
```